# Linear Algebra beginner problem: Vector visualization

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

Hi guys,

I have a linear algebra beginner problem. I have problem with the first part of the problem which asks me to determine the point of adding three fourth of V and one-fourth of W.

The solution says, I should go to three fourths of the way to V starting from W. I can solve this algebraically but cannot visualize how the solution fits.

Can somebody please explain.

Thanks,
Masharul

Comment: Visually, $\frac{1}{4}w + \frac{3}{4}v$ means going $1/4$ units in direction of $w$ (go along the line representing $w$) and then $3/4$ units in direction of $v$. The destination should be the point which divides the line in ratio $3:1$, closer to $v$ (so it is the midpoint of $u$ and $v$)

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you please explain why the points lie on the line joining v and w always where linear combinations of v and w equal to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several good answers to your particular question.

Here's a more general answer for a more general situation, that may help you:

As $t$ varies the points $p = tv + (1-t)w$ traverse the line in the plane joining the (tip of) $v$ to the (tip of) $w$. When $t=1$ you're at $p=v$. When $t=0$ you're at $p=w$. For $t$ between $0$ and $1$ you're at the points between $v$ and $w$. For $t < 0$ you're "beyond" $w$, for  $t > 1  $ you're "beyond" $v$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you please explain why the points lie on the line joining v and w always where linear combinations of v and w equal to 1?

Answer (score 2):

In the following image, the point marked with the circle visualises the result of adding three quarters of $\mathbf{v}$ and one quarter of $\mathbf{w}$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to draw the vectors, then add them *tail* to *endpoint.* This is called the resultant vector.

Here is a link to an applet which allows you to see how changing the vectors changes the resultant vector.
http://math.mercyhurst.edu/~lwilliams/Applets/VectorAddition.html